# How to execute the new page by retrieving the Json Post results from the source page?

Tags: asp.net, json

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET. I have a page where user can put advertisements. So after user fills the required fields I am putting those records in a Json array and Post them to use from another page.

I am using this code to submit the Json array by code behind.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51247//Check.aspx");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;


        //Put the post data into the request
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
```

So I put a break point in the Check.aspx to check wthether Json array getting or not. Everything works fine. But the problem is instead of Check.aspx page its again land to my source page. What I want to do is execute the my New page ( Check.aspx)  not this page. So how to do that?

I set PotbackUrl of button to redirect to that page but then Json array is become empty. So how to execute my new page by considering my Json array?

Comment: From code it seems , you are posting some data to 2nd page ( check.aspx), when you do that like this request.post ( one which you used), it will POST data , that does not mean that source page will redirect to check.aspx, rather request will be send to check.aspx programatically, nothing else will happen.

Comment: Thank you Arindam. You understood my scenario well. What should I do to POST data and then redirect to 2nd page? Remember If user doesn't satisfied he should be able to go back to previous page.

Comment: After posting , you can do simple `response.redirect` to check.aspx or anyother required page.

Comment: Its not working bro. I already used it. but then Json array got empty in check.aspx. In post situation it has values. I think page executing twice and the 2nd time Post values are not there.

Comment: I would suggest, simply your solution, modify check.aspx to get params like `Request.Form["input"]` and in source page , just use Form Posting to check.aspx  like `<form action="check.aspx: ..` .